# how to distribute requests of JMeter test plan among 2 nodes which are behind the Load balancer, Both node's IP is not public IP?

Tags: jmeter, load-balancing

I am using JMeter 3.1

We have a load balancer with public IP (i.e: 192.87.00.00) having SSL implemented and we use that IP to communicate with LB and 
LB will decide which node has currently least number requests so it will get that call.

Behind LB there are 2 nodes with non-public IP and non-secure protocol and in both nodes we implement session replication.

Whenever i run my JMeter Test then all my request went to any single node every time as per the configuration settings of LB. Now i 
have been asked to design a test plan in which all requests distributed among both nodes randomly.

I created following test:

```
Test Plan
 DNS Cache Manager
 HTTP Cookie Manager
 HTTP Cache Manager
Thread Group
    Req 1
    Req 2
    Req 3
```

[Test Plan and DNS Cache Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJqED.png)

[TG and HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGSU.png)

In the http request i put the Load balancer Public IP, Port and select "httpClient4" in Implementation dropdown.
In the DNS Cache Manager i select "Use custom DNS resolver" and in DNS Server section i define IP addresses of both Nodes.

When i run my test plan i noticed that all my requests are goes to single node. i verified this from tailing both nodes tomcat
log in a putty console and to see which node is getting the request.
I study the DNS Cache Manager in Apache JMeter help and some blogs, i implement what i learnt please help me in this regard.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The keep-alive is on in your HTTP Sampler. Turn it off.

I don't know what LB you're using, though I presume it works on TCP level rather then terminate HTTP(S) there.
So in this case, it just tunnels the packets to the actual servers. And with keep-alive, it obviously sticks to whatever one it choose at the beginning.